# MS SQL Query : Convert date and time output to different Format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I made a query to get all the data out of MS SQL that was put in the DB between 2 dates.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(30), [date], 113) as "Date"
FROM [I3_IC].[dbo].[Be]
Where [date] >= '2017-03-13T00:00:00.000' AND [date] <= '2017-03-19T00:00:00.000'
```

The output will be: 13 Mar 2017 10:40:13:017

And I want it to be: 13-03-2017 10:40

Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: Just convert to a smaller char - char(16) in thia case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm') as [Date]
FROM [I3_IC].[dbo].[Be]
WHERE [date] >= '2017-03-13T00:00:00.000' 
AND [date] <= '2017-03-19T00:00:00.000';
```

As an aside, you need to be careful with the conditions you use to select your date range (`<= '2017-03-19T00:00:00.000'` will actually select `'2017-03-19T00:00:00.000'`, is that what you want?)

Comment: Perhaps mention the difference of hh vs HH  12 hr vs 24 hr  (Plus1)

Comment: Thanks Lamak, that did the trick. If I run the query now, it gives me the right data back, and its the data between that date range. It should be easier if I could adjust the ranges to a friendlier format:)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to sql server 2012, concatenating two [**`convert()`** styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select convert(char(10),getdate(),105)+' '+convert(char(5),getdate(),108)
```

returns: `24-03-2017 16:05`

In sql server 2012+ you can use [**`format()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) as in the answer by Lamak.

```
select format(getdate(),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')
```

returns: `24-03-2017 16:05`

But `format()` can be slower, take a look here: [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

---

In a quick test on my system, concatenating `convert()` was much faster than `format()` for this (except for when selecting top 1 ordered by unformatted value).

```
+---------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  func   | total_elapsed_time | avg_elapsed_time | total_worker_time | avg_worker_time | total_clr_time |                                                       t                                                        |
+---------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| convert |               7000 | 1400.00          |              7000 | 1400.00         |              0 | DECLARE @d CHAR(10);SELECT @d = convert(char(10),d,105)+' '+convert(char(5),d,108) FROM dbo.dtTest ORDER BY d; |
| format  |             135000 | 27000.00         |            135000 | 27000.00        |         128000 | DECLARE @d CHAR(10);SELECT @d = format(d,'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm') FROM dbo.dtTest ORDER BY d;                       |
| convert |              14000 | 2800.00          |             14000 | 2800.00         |              0 | SELECT d = convert(char(10),d,105)+' '+convert(char(5),d,108) FROM dbo.dtTest ORDER BY d;                      |
| format  |             143000 | 28600.00         |            143000 | 28600.00        |         123000 | SELECT d = format(d,'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm') FROM dbo.dtTest ORDER BY d;                                            |
| convert |               1000 | 200.00           |              1000 | 200.00          |              0 | SELECT TOP (1) convert(char(10),d,105)+' '+convert(char(5),d,108) FROM dbo.dtTest ORDER BY d;                  |
| format  |               1000 | 200.00           |              1000 | 200.00          |           1000 | SELECT TOP (1) format(d,'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm') FROM dbo.dtTest ORDER BY d;                                        |
| convert |               4000 | 800.00           |              4000 | 800.00          |              0 | DECLARE @d CHAR(16);SELECT @d = convert(char(10),d,105)+' '+convert(char(5),d,108) FROM dbo.dtTest ORDER BY d; |
| format  |             105000 | 21000.00         |            105000 | 21000.00        |          95000 | DECLARE @d CHAR(16);SELECT @d = format(d,'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm') FROM dbo.dtTest ORDER BY d;                       |
+---------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The test is a modification of the test script included in the article by Aaron Bertrand. Modified version is on [pastebin, here.](http://pastebin.com/GWvJP5ES)